# How to get vertex connected (there is a path) to 3 vertices

Tags: gremlin

I'm trying to build a graph to store temporal change of users friends. In the graph below I want to get all followers, who follow both V1 and V2 (intersection) for a particular date (d1), that is vertex v3 as it's connected both to v1 and v2 for d1

I tried to start the query from v2<-follows-t2<-follows<-x->follows->t1-follows->v1, but I don't know how to connect the d1 node as this splits the path on t2.

```
g.V(v2_id).inE('follows').otherV().as_('t2').inE('follows').otherV().as_('v3').outE('follows').otherV().as_('t1').outE('follows').otherV().hasId(v1_id).select('v3')
```

Could you please give me a hint or gremlin trick how I specify that t2 and t1 should be linked by d1

Ids of d1,v1 and v2 are known so I could also start from d1 I guess

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `v1`, `v2` and `d1` are vertices (not just ids):

```
g.V(v1, v2).as("a").in("follows").
  filter(out("of_day").is(d1)).in("follows").
  group().by().by(select("a").fold()).unfold().
  and(select(values).unfold().is(v1),
      select(values).unfold().is(v2)).
  select(keys)
```

However, if `v1`, `v2` and `d1` are just ids, it's not much different:

```
g.V(v1, v2).as("a").in("follows").
  filter(out("of_day").hasId(d1)).in("follows").
  group().by().by(select("a").fold()).unfold().
  and(select(values).unfold().hasId(v1),
      select(values).unfold().hasId(v2)).
  select(keys)
```

The queries above are good if there can be more than 2 inputs. If there are always only 2 inputs, then the following query should be more efficient:

```
g.V(v1).in("follows").
  filter(out("of_day").is(d1)).
  in("follows").
  filter(out("follows").filter(out("of_day").is(d1)).
         out("follows").is(v2))
```